# Flag & close as duplicate not working with Opera

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, flagging, duplicates

I am trying to flag [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62866/are-these-the-correct-functions-for-creating-a-database-connection-creating-tabl) as a duplicate of [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62864/are-these-the-correct-functions-for-cleaning-data-to-be-sent-to-database-and-ins), but I cannot seem to get it to work as the button is greyed out.

I tried to enter:

- `https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62864/are-these-the-correct-functions-for-cleaning-data-to-be-sent-to-database-and-ins`
- `62864`
- etc.

But none of them work. Voting to close as a duplicate has the same problem.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: flagging as duplicate: button greyed out]

I'm using Opera (on Linux Mint).

If I'm using Firefox it works. Can someone confirm if this is just my version of Opera, or if this is a general issue?

Comment: Is it still buggy ?

Comment: @Marc-Andre yes, for me it still looks like in the screenshot.

Comment: My gut reaction here is "Opera + Linux Mint is not a super-common setup." Technically, we [support only current and previous versions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) of Opera. What version are you using?

Comment: @Pops good point. 12.16, and I'm just realizing that yes, that's pretty old (there doesn't seem to be a new version for linux, so I guess I'll have to switch to firefox).